# FTP upload/download freezing and generally slow

Tags: windows, ftp, freeze, filezilla

I've got 100 mbps and can download from Steam with about 8-12 MB/s.
Also I have an upload speed of 4-5 MB/s but those speeds are never actually used while doing something using FTP.

The maximum download using FTP is about 2.8 MB/s, same for upload. Also it freezes every few seconds.

Any tips on this? I am using Windows 10. This problem occurs on different FTP-Servers.

Comment: Start by plugging an Ethernet cable into the computer and modem. Test using speediest.net.  Add the router, stay with an Ethernet cable tho.  Test using speedtest.net.   Move to wifi. Test using speedtest.net.   There is no magic in determining which network segment is causing a slowdown.  Once you figure out which segment is the problem then you can work on fixing it. FYI- this question in very similar form has been asked 100's of times.

Comment: Also try a different FTP program. It may be a bug or built in limit.